# Lua moving table up causing nil value error

Tags: indexing, lua, null, lua-table

I have a table of tables which represents a 65*65 square grid where each element is integer values. It represents the area around an actor and the actor can move in the four cardinal directions and as they do I need the table to move with them so they remain in the center square 33,33.

Rather than moving the elements of the table I instead have two pointers tableIndex.left and tableIndex.down which store the indexes of the far left column of the bottom row respectively, they both start at 65. I have three helper functions to perform operations on the table, all take the arguments x1,x2,y1,y2 where x1 and y1 are the co-ordinates to start the function at and x2 and y2 are the co ordinates to end the function.

These functions are tableInit which creates tables in all the values between x1 and x2. zero table which fills all of the entries in the specified range with 0 and clear table which sets all the entries in the specified range to nil.

```
function movetable(direction)
    --function to move our probability histogram 
    -- 0 is up, 1 is right, 2 is down, 3 is left
    --as a note robotSpeed = 1
    if direction == 0 then
        tableIndex.down += robotSpeed
        zerotable(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.down+64,tableIndex.down+64)
        cleartable(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.down-1,tableIndex.down-1)
    elseif direction == 1 then
        tableIndex.left += robotSpeed
        tableInit(tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.left+64)
        zerotable(tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.down,tableIndex.down+64)
        cleartable(tableIndex.left-1,tableIndex.left-1,tableIndex.down,tableIndex.down+64)
    elseif direction == 2 then
        tableIndex.down -= robotSpeed
        zerotable(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.down,tableIndex.down)
        cleartable(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left+64,tableIndex.down+65,tableIndex.down+65)
    else
        tableIndex.left -= robotSpeed
        tableInit(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left)
        zerotable(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left,tableIndex.down,tableIndex.down+64)
        cleartable(tableIndex.left+65,tableIndex.left+65,tableIndex.down,tableIndex.down+64)
    end
end
```

The table is called later in the program,in the following section of code, which is where the error is thrown "Attempt to perform arithmetic on field '?' a nil value. This occurs when i and j are 0. This only occurs after the table has last moved up so dir==0 and the error ceases to exist if I comment out the cleartable call in my movetable function for the case when dir==0.

```
for i=0,64 do
    for j=0,64 do
        --Robot is at 33 33 so we know there isnt an obstacle here
        if i ~= 32 and j ~= 32 then
            --This is the equation from the paper which tells us which direction the result is in
            local tan = atan2(i-33,j-33)+0.25
            if (tan > 1) tan = tan-1
            local dInD = flr(360*tan)
            --Our polar histogram has sectors ALPHA degrees wide, this rounds the direction down to a multiple of 
            --the sector size so we can use it as an index
            local dir = dInD - dInD%ALPHA
            polarHist[dir] += certaintyTable[tableIndex.left+i][tableIndex.down+j]
        end
    end
```

As a note I dont have access to the standard lua libraries.

and here is cleartable in case I am doing that wrong

```
function cleartable(x1,x2,y1,y2)
    if x1 == x2 then
        for j=y1,y2 do
            certaintyTable[x1][j] = nil
        end
    elseif y1==y2 then
        for i=x1,x2 do
            certaintyTable[i][y1] = nil
        end
    else
        for i=x1,x2 do
            for j=y1,y2 do
                certaintyTable[i][j] = nil
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks for looking at my problem

Comment: Change `atan2(i-33,j-33)` to `atan2(i-32,j-32)`

Comment: Change `if i ~= 32 and j ~= 32` to `if i ~= 32 or j ~= 32`

Comment: Please give the result of `atan2(-1,-2)` to understand what this function returns.  And show how do you initialize the `polarHist` array.  And on which line exactly the error is thrown?

Comment: "For example, atan2(1, 1) is 0.875 (7/4 pi radians, or 315 degrees), and atan2(-1, -1) is 0.375 (3/4 pi radians, or 135 degrees). Similarly, atan2(0, 1) is 0.75"
Polar hist is initialized as so, 
`function polarHistInit()

 local sectorNum = 360/ALPHA

 polarHist.size = sectorNum
 for i=0,sectorNum do
  polarHist[i*ALPHA] = 0
 end
end`
The Line that throws the error is
`polarHist[dir] += certaintyTable[tableIndex.left+i][tableIndex.down+j]`

Comment: What is `atan2(0,0)`?  Does problem still exist after making corrections described in my first two comments?

Comment: `atan2(0,0)` is 0.75 and `atan2(-1,-2)' is 0.3238. The problem does indeed persist after those corrections .

Comment: Have you called `tableIndex.left = 1; tableIndex.down = 1; tableInit(tableIndex.left, tableIndex.left + 64)` at the initialization phase?

Comment: They start at 65 rather than 1 as they can be decremented by up to 64, so their min value is one. At initialization I call `tableIndex = {["left"] = 65, ["down"] = 65}` then `tableInit(tableIndex.left,tableIndex.left+64)`

Comment: I'm giving up  :-)  There are no more errors in the part of code you have shown.

Comment: Thanks for trying!